# Ubuntu 20.04 - Can't update mysql-client and mysql-server packages

Tags: apt, 20.04, mysql

Before updating to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04, I decided to first update MySQL from 5.5 to 8.0.

I then updated to Ubuntu 20.04 and all was well, until some updates for mysql-client and mysql-server came out.  Neither will install.

**apt-get upgrade** returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  mysql-client mysql-server
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

I then typed **apt-get install mysql-client** and received:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-client : Depends: mysql-client-8.0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But mysql-client-8.0 Is installed (UPDATE: oops, it actually isn't):

**apt policy mysql-client-8.0**

```
mysql-client-8.0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3
  Version table:
     8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 500
        500 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
     8.0.19-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

After that....

**apt-get install mysql-client-8.0**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-client-8.0 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And finally tried...

**apt-get install mysql-commmon**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mysql-common is already the newest version (8.0.28-1ubuntu18.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

**apt-cache policy mysql-common**

```
mysql-common:
  Installed: 8.0.28-1ubuntu18.04
  Candidate: 8.0.28-1ubuntu18.04
  Version table:
 *** 8.0.28-1ubuntu18.04 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 500
        500 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

I've found posts online where people ran into similar, but not identical problems... not quite sure how to go about fixing this without causing major issues.  I run a website on this server and don't want to irreperably harm anything, but do want to get this fixed.

Thanks!

**SOLVED by:**
apt remove mysql-common
THEN
apt install mysql-server

Comment: `apt-cache policy mysql-common` please.

Comment: Updated main post.

Comment: Deinstall any mysql package and install     them new.

Comment: Will I lose all of my config, etc?  What's the safest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same issue. Once the server updated to 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3, MySQL does not work any longer. I cannot start it. It goes into an infinite loop trying to run the update process.

if I run `top` I have the following:

```
2395 mysql     20   0   27.3g   2.3g  23164 S 100.0   7.2   3:27.15 mysqld
```

Which runs with 100% of one CPU.

And on the mysql error logs I have it frozen at:

```
2022-05-05T16:29:47.691578Z 4 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '80028' to '80029' started.
2022-05-05T16:34:12.394803Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax 'expire-logs-days' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use binlog_expire_logs_seconds instead.
2022-05-05T16:34:12.395761Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) starting as process 2393
2022-05-05T16:34:12.418552Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-05-05T16:34:13.414340Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-05-05T16:34:13.848163Z 4 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '80028' to '80029' started.
```

Comment: Thankfully my MySQL install is still working.... but I have not went too far on trying to fix this, have been fearful of breaking it.

Comment: Well, unfortunately I cannot loose that data. So I will try to have another new instance installed and use an older dump. But I would like to be able to recover this. This happened last night. Was fine until this new update came.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me it was because I had `max_binlog_size   = 100M` in mysqld.cnf, and the size limit had been hit. I deleted all the binlog files in /var/lin/mysql and emptied the binlog.index file and mysql started without issues.